# How to grab attachment programmatically (C#) from a POP3 mail?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, pop3

Is there any C# API for this task? Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I've used [/n Software](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/) in the past with success.  Not free, but hey, you get to blame someone else if it doesn't work! (in other words, you get tech support from the company)

They have a free trial as well.